# RSA Private Keys - iOS

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, openssl

I want to create RSA private keys using modulus and exponent in Objective C.

Below is the equvalent code to create the key in JAVA.

```
RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(m, e);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
factory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

I am using openSSL library in iOS, but I could not find a way to create the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis, I found out there is no library to support for generating RSA private Keys using modulus and exponent in iOS. I even tried openSSL library.

So I have decided to get Private Keys from server and I signed(SHA256) with message and then generated a signature token using openSSL library.

Instead of puling from server, I have also generated Private Keys in PEM format using some Python Script and loaded them in the iOS application.

Below library is for OpenSSL iOS integration

> pod "MIHCrypto", "~> 0.4.1"

This is the python script for generating Private Keys with modulus & exponent.

> https://github.com/ius/rsatool